# locked root with no other user account login ubuntu ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-server

i think i have made a big mistake
on a vps ubuntu tls through ssh i locked root acount without first to make a user's account login.

I have active winscp connection with the server and i can edit or upload new /etc/passwd and shadow files (passwd- shadow- also exists)

**some lines from passwd** ( i have created user vmail but hadn't add password/login?)

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
vmail:x:5000:5000::/var/spool/vmail:
```

**/etc/passwd-**

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
virtual:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/virtual:/bin/bash
vmail:x:5000:5000::/var/spool/vmail:
```

**/etc/shadow**

```
root:!:16514:0:99999:7:::
vmail:!:16513:0:99999:7:::
```

/etc/shadow- (changed abit middle letters in pass)

```
root:$6$PRLOUfho$IzxfU9eeHgrytOkckbsdb7neDIz.3v9swIWOk0osPfAMVXil0VPArTdzwbD766G7232DPKylZomL/o/50ZtIh0:16514:0:99999:7:::
vmail:*:16513:0:99999:7:::
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

- SCP is just one of several protocols that work over the same connection. You should be able to open up a terminal session from winscp and just run `passwd`
- you could try and make a backup of your /etc/shadow, and replace the root line with the line from a system where you know the root password.

Comment: thanks for the info. when i try to run a terminal session it tries to reconnect to server (so it get access deny)

i know the password u just have locked it. is there anyway to unlock it through the files?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If you know the password, why are you locked out?

Comment: Sorry for my low knowlegde i had changed the passworded for root and then used command
sudo passwd -l root

I though that just lock the account (but the password stay the same) until somehow i unlock the root account and will be able to login with that same password

Comment: that's not about knowledge -- I simply don't understand the problem you're having. Could you *explain* what the problem is? What *can't* you do?

Comment: `i changed root's password to : 000000`
`typed : sudo passwd -l root`
`terminate the ssh session`
`on login i type root and password 000000`
`i get Access denied`
`command sudo passwd -l root reset password or lock the account?`
`if it just locks is it possible to unlock it from scp?`

Comment: what do you mean with "locks"?

Comment: i wanted to just change the password for the root and i follow the instruction of this link (till the end :) ) http://askubuntu.com/questions/294946/how-to-change-root-password-in-ubuntu thanks for the replying ! i got rescue mode from hoster and reset the pass

Answer (score 1):

Did you try upload a new /etc/shadow? Replace the "!" in your root line of /etc/shadow to the encrypted password.